# Create HTML table from Excel (xls / xlsx) with .NET

Tags: c#, html, .net, excel, converters

I want to create an HTML table with all CSS from an Excel file with C#.

i tried my to create a library for doing that but it seems it has so many exception and problems.

I've googled a lot, but there was nothing out there.

Is there any solution to achieve that?

Comment: Consider http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Spreadsheet/Overview & nuget package :  Install-Package GemBox.Spreadsheet

Comment: [XlsxToHtmlConverter](https://github.com/Fei-Sheng-Wu/XlsxToHtmlConverter) is a free xlsx to html converter which under the MIT lincense. It uses .Net Core 3.0 as framework and only depends on the Open Xml SDK. And it is 100% written by C#.

Comment: @FeiShengWu That's interesting i will look at that. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GemBox.Spreadsheet has a [feature to convert Excel files to HTML](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Spreadsheet/CommonUses/Convert) and other common formats and has a free version.

http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Spreadsheet/Overview

NuGet: Install-Package GemBox.Spreadsheet

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've checked that. it has limitation for 150 row. i have at least 2000 row

Comment: @PouyaSamie I did not know that pouya jan! sorry. but i think you could read excel file row by row and generate HTML table by yourselfe. It's easy.

Comment: Dear Iman the problem is i should generate Css and some other stuffs for my generated table and it'snot that easy... bazam merc ;)